# Can't see any response returns from php web service

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a simple `php` file to retrieve data from `MySQL`database.And I have hosted it in my `wampserver`. This is my web service.

```
config.php

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db('tuts_rest', $conn);

global.php


<?php

include 'signup.php';
include 'getLocation.php';
$app->get('/users/','getLocationData');
$app->run();
?>
```

getLocationData.php

```
<?php


function getLocationData()
{
    global $app;
    $req = $app->request(); // Getting parameter with names
    $tableName = $req->params('location'); // Getting parameter with names

    $sql="SELECT * FROM location";
    try
    {
        $dbCon = getConnection();
        $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("table", $tableNameName);
        $stmt->execute();
        $locationData = array();
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {

            $locationData['LocationData'][] = $row;
        }

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($locationData);
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }



}

?>
```

This is how I call the web service:

```
http://localhost/GISWebService/getLocation.php/getLocationData
```

But I don't get any output:

[image: see below image]

Comment: What is `$app`?

Comment: $app is defined in global.php